# Clean ArchitectureのISPの説明でUser1の再コンパイルが必要になる理由がわかりません

Tags: アーキテクチャ

まず私はプログラミング初心者です。業務経験などありません。独習C#を一通り読んでGoFを覚えた(あまり理解はしていません)程度の知識です。

本題です。Clean Architectureという本のISPの解説を読んでいただくのが早いと思いますが、一応解説を書きます。クラス図は次のサイトに載っていますので日本語を読むのが面倒な場合は該当箇所を見てください(https://scrapbox.io/mwtndmik/Clean_Architecture)。まずOPSというクラスがop1,op2,op3というメソッドを持っています。そしてUser1,User2,User3がそれぞれop1,op2,op3のみを使っています。このとき「op2のコードを変更したときに、User1の再コンパイルと再デプロイが必要になる」と書いてあります。
これを改善するためにOPSがU1Ops,U2Ops,U3Opsというインターフェース(それぞれop1,op2,op3を実装する必要がある)を継承し、User1,User2,User3はそれぞれのインターフェースを使用します。このとき「OPSに変更があったとしても、もしそれがUser1に関係のない部分であれば、User1の再コンパイルと再デプロイは不要になる」と書かれています。

疑問点1:なぜUser1の再コンパイルなどが必要になるのかがわかりません（どのような仕組みでこうなるのか）。あるいは再コンパイルが必要になるものとそうでないものの違いはどのように判断されるのでしょうか。
疑問点2:そもそもUser1が何なのかがわかりません、これはクラスなのでしょうか。
疑問点3:インターフェースを使って改善した後にUser1に関係のある部分を変更した場合、User1の再コンパイルなどは必要になるのでしょうか。

これらの疑問を解決するために日本語や英語でいろいろと検索をしたつもりですが、解決できなかったので質問しました。質問が曖昧だと思った場合はそれが明確になるように促していただけると幸いです。なにか参考になりそうなサイトや本があれば最悪それだけ提示していただいても結構です。元の本に何らかの言語でソースコードが書いてあったわけではありません。ここで質問をするのは初めてなのでなにかおかしなことがあれば言ってください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 疑問点1:なぜUser1の再コンパイルなどが必要になるのかがわかりません（どのような仕組みでこうなるのか）。あるいは再コンパイルが必要になるものとそうでないものの違いはどのように判断されるのでしょうか。

同じ質問が [Interface Segregation Principle in Clean Architecture](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/384787/interface-segregation-principle-in-clean-architecture) に上がっていました。しかし、そこの回答でも現在使われているようなプログラミング言語ではUser1の再コンパイルは必要ではないし、話題をそこにフォーカスさせるのも例として不適切と書かれています。なので、気にしなくていいと思います。

試しに手元でJavaとC++で同じことを試してみましたが、OPSの関数の実装を修正してコンパイル（とリンク）が走るのはOPSのモジュールだけです。OPSの関数名（メソッドシグネチャ）を変えると当然関数名を変えたクラスもコンパイルが走りますが、それと関係ないクラスまでリコンパイルする必要はありません。

> 疑問点2:そもそもUser1が何なのかがわかりません、これはクラスなのでしょうか。

クラスという認識でいいと思います。

例えばJavaのWEB開発っぽく書くと

- `class User1Controller`
- `class User2Controller`
- `class User3Controller`

がそれぞれ抽象クラス（＝インターフェース）として

- `interface U1Ops`
- `interface U2Ops`
- `interface U3Ops`

を呼び出していて

具象クラス（実装）

- `class Ops implements U1Ops, U2Ops, U3Ops`

interfaceを作ってない場合、具象クラスの実装の修正がそのままUser1,2,3に影響します（引数や返り値の型など）。interfaceを作っておけば具象クラス側の修正だけで済みます。
インターフェースを分離することで、具象クラスの変化（例えば利用してるライブラリ・フレームワークの変更、仕様の変更、利用するはずのAPIの変更）に巻き込まれないようになる。

みたいな感じになると思います。

> 疑問点3:インターフェースを使って改善した後にUser1に関係のある部分を変更した場合、User1の再コンパイルなどは必要になるのでしょうか。

疑問点１の回答と同じで、ISPの話題で再コンパイルのことは気にしないでいいです

Comment: ちょっと補足情報。javaの場合、定数(static final)を参照している場合は再コンパイル必要ですよね（実行時参照ではないから。）。

Comment: それはつまり上の例で言えば、OPSのop1が定数だった場合その値を変更したらUser1の再コンパイルが必要ということでしょうか(それなら理解ができます)、あるいは定数であるop2の変更もUser1の再コンパイルにつながるのでしょうか？

Comment: OPS.op1を直接参照していればなりますよ。昔会社名を定数で決めていて、社名変更の際に、定数だけ変更してそのクラス（パッケージ）だけをビルドし、テストしていたところ、「社名が変わらない！！なぜだ！」とやっているあれなことがありました。 逆にOPT#getOpt1()というメソッドを擁してそれを使っていればコンパイルは不要です。I/Fを導入して直接参照をやめれば同様の効果があります。ちょっと実験をしたので、回答に追記しておきます。

Comment: より深く理解したいためさらに質問があります。「interfaceを作っておけば具象クラス側の修正だけで済みます」とありますが、このメリットの確認をしたいです。interfaceを実装するクラスの変更だけで済めば、そのinterfaceを利用するクラスがいくつかあったとして、修正範囲が狭まるから(ある意味で修正用のコードの再利用的なことができるから)良いということでしょうか？

Comment: その理解で問題ないかと、実際に書いてみると実感できますよ。小さなプログラム。

Answer (score 1):

コメントにかけないので、ここに。ちょっと試してみました。下記のように、OPSのpublic static finalな定数を変更したタイミング（のみ）でUser1のハッシュ値が変わります。（ビルド結果が変わる＝再ビルド必要）

```
find . -type f -exec md5sum {} \; |grep step|grep User1
(1)2368f868b0662a860516cef4a06b22c0 *./step0/User1.class
★(2)443dd309c307113720494576bdc8ec13 *./step1/User1.class 定数(static final)の値を変更した場合。
(3)443dd309c307113720494576bdc8ec13 *./step2/User1.class (2)のfinal変数を変更した場合 
(4)443dd309c307113720494576bdc8ec13 *./step3/User1.class (3)のfinalメソッドを変更した場合
(5)443dd309c307113720494576bdc8ec13 *./step4/User1.class (4)のメソッドを変更した場合
```